# SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below

Tags: jsf-2, exception, websphere, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to use some error pages in a JSF application which is deployed on IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.0.0.8. They are declared as follows in `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error403.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/expired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

However, they don't seem to work. For instance, when I get a `ViewExpiredException` after restarting the application, I'm not redirected to the error page, but I get the following `SRVE0260E` error in the server log:

```
Error Page Exception
SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

Original Exception:
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: /help.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /help.xhtml
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: Faces Servlet
Error Stack:
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /help.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /help.xhtml
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:128)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3774)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)



Error Page Exception:
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
Error Code: 0
Target Servlet:
Error Stack:
javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
     at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:321)
     at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualInstance(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:124)
     at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:95)
     at org.apache.webbeans.conversation.ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_40.isTransient(ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_40.java)
     at org.apache.webbeans.jsf.WebBeansPhaseListener.beforePhase(WebBeansPhaseListener.java:93)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:76)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:160)
     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3276)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:3804)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3785)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: This exception is not thrown during an ajax request and you'd have exactly the same problem when removing the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`, so that part is actually not relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry, I removed this part.

Comment: The `SRVE0260E` will be thrown when the error page is not reachable for the request dispatcher. E.g. the path is wrong (404), or the path is restricted (401/403). Make sure that the path is correct (it should also trigger `FacesServlet`!) and that it's public (no login required). An easy way to verify the one and other is to enter the full URL to the error page in the webbrowser's address bar yourself and look what you get and then compare that URL with the `<location>` and then if necessary fix the `<location>` accordingly.

Comment: I'm able to reach the e.g. error500.xhtml http://localhost:PORT/CONTEXTROOT/error500.xhtml. At moment its the only error page. The errorpage just contains some static html and #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']} to navigate back. Causes this the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the Error Page handling is going through the JSF processor, but for some reason the requestDestroyed() method has already fired ending the request context.  The CDI PhaseListener is then throwing the exception when it can't find the request context.

You should be able to work around this issue by using a non-JSF based error page.  Perhaps a static file, or JSP would work.

Otherwise I suggest you open a PMR so that the request issue can be resolved.